# Deserializes JSON to an object in c# using json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to convert my json into a rule object. I have been following this guide from Newtonsoft http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm.

```
public class Rule{
            public string Field { get; set; }
            public string Test { get; set; } 
            public Rule[] Cases { get; set; }
            } 
 public class Rules    {
        public List<Rule> Root{ get; set; } 
    }
```

My Json from rules.js

```
{
"Rules": [{
        "Field": "Subject",
        "Test": "^(Azure Exception)",
        "Cases": [{
            "Field": "Content",
            "Test": "Hostname: az.....(?<Hostname>[^\n])",
            "Cases": [{
                "Field": "Content",
                "Test": "Hostname:\\s+(?<Hostname>.*)\\s+Site name:\\s+(?<SiteName>.*)"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

In my main method:

```
String RulesFile = "cSharp/rules.js"; 
String Json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(RulesFile); 

Rule rule = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rule>(Json);

var rules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rules>(Json);
        //rule.Cases
        //rule.Field
        //rule.Test
        //rules.Root
     
Console.Write(rule.Field);
```

I've tested my json and i can output it in my terminal. I'm unsure how to assign each field in json to my rules objects. Looking at the newtonsoft docs this should work, but I'm not getting any output.

I want to be able to print these fields out, anyone know to do it?

Cheers all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSON string, the root object is an object with a `Rules` property. That property is an array of objects. You need to define and deserialize the root object, eg

```
class Rules 
{
    public Rule[] Rules{get;set;}
}

var rules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rules>(Json);
```

You can generate the DTOs requires for deserialization in Visual Studio by copying the JSON string and select [Paste JSON as Classes](https://www.meziantou.net/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-paste-as-json.htm) in the Edit menu. You can also generate classes by using an online converter like [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now get `Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[cSharp.Rule] because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.` Any ideas?

Comment: @Greg Not quite. It's an object with `List<Rules> Rules` in it. You don't have such an object

Comment: I think because the json he is trying to Deserialize is actually 

`public class JsonData
{
     public List<Rule> Rules {get;set;}
}`

Comment: Thanks - I've added that in now however i get the error `'Rules': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type [cSharp]csharp(CS0542)`

Comment: Try changing the root type name to `Root`